# Radius of Turn Query

Tags: aircraft-performance

[image]

I am making a project related to flight paths. If we are given two points in space (lat,long) and the flight headings(angles) that the flight should attain at that points.

By using the radius of turn formula, I checked whether the flight can reach the next point or not, but how can I check whether the flight can reach both the points with the specified heading or not??

Please help me out.. Thanks in advance...

Sorry for the ambiguity in the question. In the figure attached, if I need to go through points 1, 2 and 3 so on which are few points in the flight path. And if I am given (lat,long,heading the flight should attain at that point) for each point, I need to find out whether points can be reached or not. Also please suggest me the solution if I need the same heading at all the three points (say x).

And the flight should not take more than 1 turn i.e. loops are not allowed (flight should always move towards the destination).

[image]

Now, i need to head from source to destination along points 1,2,3 with same heading(q) at these three points. For example take q as the angle between source and destination. Now i want to move towards destination i.e by not turning back and no loops. Just want know whether its feasible for flight with specific radius of turn to reach the next point or not.

Or what should the minimum vertical distance and horizontal distance between the points be in order to satisfy both the points.

[image: Figure 3]

But we can't determine the minimum radius exactly right?? In the figure 3, point 1 can be reached with the specified heading with distance below 2 * rmin. So the condition be like delta(x) > rmin definitely because it can't reach close neighboring points but what should be next condition to check whether it can reach with required heading or not. If it is like delta(x) > 2 * rmin then figure 3 would contradict it, right?

Comment: If you can check one, you can check next one after that in the same way, no?

Comment: Tags are quite off and the title is also non-descriptive. Also, you can always reach another location, only question is how many maneuvers you have to do in order to obtain said result.

Comment: This sounds more like a geometry puzzle than an aviation question. If we do not know the start and end points, how should we help with the optimum route, given that you need to avoid turns? I feel like the expert in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg).

Comment: @amarender: Please state your problem with all boundary conditions. I expect that you will help yourself the most when you have clearly expressed what exactly you want to know.

Comment: @amarender: please note that in your second figure you have 2 turns between each pair of points.

Comment: @Federico Ya even though it has 2 turns , its always moving towards the destination which is my requirement. And also it can have more turns but not take loops or reverse directions ..

Comment: `what should the minimum vertical distance and horizontal distance between the points be in order to satisfy both the points` I strongly suggest you to study a bit of euclidean geometry and basic flight kinematics.

Answer (score 2):

The difference in headings gives you the number of degrees you need to turn. The distance between the two points then becomes a secant to the turning circle which should give you the turn radius by applying some basic geometry. I assume that the turn starts on point 1 and ends on reaching point 2. Like this:

[image]

Now you first need to calculate the turn radius, using the equation for secant length: Start with the difference between the two headings and call that angle $\varphi$. Then the difference between two points $s$ is $$s = 2\cdot r \cdot sin\frac{\varphi}{2}$$
Since you know $s$, you can calculate the turn radius $r$ by a simple transformation: $$r = \frac{s}{2\cdot sin \frac{\varphi}{2}}$$

Now you need to check whether the airplane will be able to turn with that radius. This depends on wing loading $\frac{m}{S}$, density of air $\rho$ and maximum lift coefficient $c_{L_{max}}$, and the equation for the minimum turn radius is $$r_{min} = \frac{2\cdot m}{c_{L_{max}}\cdot S \cdot \rho}$$

Compare both values of $r$ and check if $r > r_{min}$. Then the turn is physically possible.

Now I only hope that this is really what you asked. Your question leaves a lot of room for interpretation.

---

EDIT: @amarender has updated the question. Now the heading is identical at all intermediate points, and below is one of many possible solutions (blue line):

[image]

I indicated with pie segments where the turns are; of course, the one single turn condition has to be interpreted as one turn per intermediate point. The sections between the turns are straight, and all bring the aircraft closer to the destination if the heading at the intermediate points is identical to the heading from target to destination.

When do we have a condition where a solution is not possible? Only if the points are too close together to satisfy the condition of the minimum turning radius. By rotating the coordinate system such that the desired heading at the points is parallel to the x axis, this is easier to show:

[image]

The distance between two points in the direction of the desired heading $\Delta x$ must not be smaller than the diameter of the minimum possible circle ($2\cdot r_{min}$) using the equation above. The green line above is for $\Delta x > 2\cdot r_{min}$, and the red line for the boundary condition $\Delta x = 2\cdot r_{min}$. To be precise, the equation above does not put a limit on the maximum load factor $n_{z_{max}}$ - if this needs to be considered, the minimum radius is:
$$r_{min} = \frac{2\cdot \frac{n_{z_{max}}}{\sqrt{n^2_{z_{max}}-1}}}{c_{L_{max}}\cdot \frac{S}{m} \cdot \rho}$$

Things get more complicated when the heading at the points is different from the heading from the source to the destination. Then $\Delta y$ becomes important as well, and when it gets large relatively to $\Delta x$, the straight connection between turns will point away from the target very soon.

Comment: this is actually only one of 12 possible situations (assuming same altitude for both points). As I said in my comment to the question, it is always possible to `reach both the points with the specified heading`, this answer checks only if this is possible performing only one turn.

Comment: @Federico: You are right, I took a guess what amarender might mean. But flying an arbitrary path between the two points is trivial, so I took the case with the shortest circular connection between both.

Comment: I understand that, I took the liberty of underline this since you did not explicitely stated the assumption in your answer. Also, there are optimal solutions also for when $r<r_{min}$, but they involve multiple turns.

Comment: I'd bet that the OP asks for reaching both points in one single turn where the turn is less than 180 degrees, and the plane is turning a constant rate all the time between the two points. Otherwise, the turn is always possible by overshooting then turning in the opposite direction. If more than one turn is allows then the question is moot, there're infinite number of solutions.

Comment: What if i need the same heading angle at all the points and flight cannot take more than one turn i.e if it heads only towards destination all the time.Flight also can't take loops. Imagine only one source and one destination and points 1,2,3 lie between them.

Comment: @PeterKämpf : Ya the flight can't attain the points with same heading in the figure which you drew. Could you explain the solution for the problem, if the flight has to move from source to destination as specified in my figure.

Comment: @PeterKämpf : Sorry if i am wrong but the case in figure 3 would contradict your answer of delta(x) being greater than 2 * rmin. If yes, what would be the minimum delta(x) in such a case.

Comment: @amarender: I don't get it. The red circles are for a minimum turnig radius equal to $\frac{\Delta x}{2}$, and the green circles for a smaller $r_{min}$. Where is the contradiction?

Comment: this question is becoming more and more about homework and is already extremely localized. Your answer already gives all the details needed, I would refrain from continuing.

Comment: @PeterKämpf : If the flight turns at the point on the green circle (intersection of green and black circle) then point 1 can be reached with the required heading, right? Then, the delta(x) is less then 2 times the minimum radius. Even the delta(x) is less than 2*rmin(can be visualized from figure) the flight will be able to reach the point 1. But we came to conclusion that delta(x) must be at least greater than 2*rmin. This is what i am concerned from the time i asked the question. May be, i was not clear in asking the question, which led to confusion, Apologies for that!!

Comment: @amarender: Yes, the above is only for $\Delta y > 2\cdot r_{min}$. But now that you know $r_{min}$, the rest is basic geometry. This forum is not for solving your geometry problems.